# Tamanho de linhas de um drop box down quando clicamos no botão "para baixo"

Tags: html, html-select

Tenho uma lista de Estados brasileiros criados com o comando `select/option` do HTML5,

Quando clico para escolher o estado, aparecem 20 linhas(estados) e ultrapassa minha caixa de texto para baixo.

Quero restringir o número de linhas/estados que aparecem depois de clicar para escolher.
Não quero usar o `size="x"` e sim quero que apareçam 10 linhas quando clico no botão para 
escolher o estado.

Comment: É uma boa pergunta, mas acho que não tem como controlar isso. A única maneira seria não usar `<select>`, e sim algum substituto feito com HTML + CSS + JavaScript.

Comment: Já tá um tempo sem atualização, mas é bem arretado o [ms-Dropdown](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown), [{demo}](https://rawgit.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown/master/index.html), note que se começar a digitar o dropdown faz o search, um pouco parecido com o menu superior esquerdo aqui do site.

Comment: 10 linhas significa que você quer exibir apenas os 10 primeiros estados? Caso positivo, e se o usuário é de um estado que não estiver sendo exibido? Você tem a imagem da tela ou maiores detalhes para adicionar na pergunta?

Comment: Você pode controlar isso no momento da listagem, caso esteja fazendo isso por um JS, se não fica complicado, teria de usar alguma das dicas acimas.

Comment: Você quer os 10 primeiros na caixa e o restante fica na barra de rolagem? se não for isso então basta você colocar apenas os 10 option's mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Entendido que no *< select>* teremos 20 *< option>* e ao clicar no select abrir uma caixa para que o usuário escolha uma opção.

- A caixa de opção abrirá com um tamanho que acomode os 10 primeiros elementos
- Os demais elementos ficarão como opção de escolha se usar a barra de rolagem

**Obs:** Se for para ter apenas 10 elementos como escolha então bastaria colocar **apenas** os 10 elementos como *< option>* não é mesmo! :)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onfocus='this.size=10;' 
onblur='this.size=1;' 
onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
     <option>12</option>
     <option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option>
      <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
  </select>
```

Quando der focus então ele vai ter size=10, quando perder o focus vai p/ 1 e change também que seria o caso do usuário selecionar um

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534569/3130590

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22709868/3987358), você consegue aumentar o tamanho quando necessário e manter o comportamento padrão quando não for necessário.

```
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>10){this.size=1;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```